# How To I dispay only subcatogory in post

Tags: php, wordpress, post

here is my code i want to display subcategory of a specific category

```
<?php
wp_dropdown_categories('orderby=name&hide_empty=0&exclude=1&hierarchical=1');  
?>
```

it display All the Category and subcatogry but i want just show only subcategory(Child) of a specific Category
Please help me.

Your reply will be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example:

```
<?php
    $parent_category_id = 12;
    $args = array(
    'orderby'            => 'name',
    'order'              => 'DESC',
    'hide_empty'         => 1,
    'exclude'            => '1',
    'child_of'           => $parent_category_id,
    'hierarchical'       => 1,
    'taxonomy'           => 'category',
    'hide_if_empty'      => false,
);
wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
```

this will display all subcategories of category 12
doc link -  [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array('child_of' => 17);
$categories = get_categories( $args );
foreach($categories as $category) { 
echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) .'" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
echo '<p> Description:'. $category->description . '</p>';
echo '<p> Post Count: '. $category->count . '</p>';  
}
```